# Use an item as hint in Spinner (default item) and hide it in the dropdown

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using the below code to select the last item of my list as hint of the spinner (ie. the default selected item in the spinner) and am trying to hide it from the dropdown menu.

```
List<String> rfpType = new ArrayList<>();
rfpType.add("Job");
rpType.add("Talent");  
rfpType.add("Vendor");
rfpType.add("Sponsor");
rfpType.add("RFP Title");

HintAdapter dataAdapter1 = new HintAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rfpType);
dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerRFPType.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
spinnerRFPType.setSelection(dataAdapter1.getCount());
```

**HintAdapter**

```
class HintAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public HintAdapter(Context context, int theLayoutResID , List<String> list){
        super(context, theLayoutResID, list);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // don't display last item. It is used as hint.
        int count = super.getCount();
        return count > 0 ? count-1 : count;
    }

}
```

But it displays the second last item as default. And hides the last item which I want to use as the hint. Suggest me a correct solution.

Comment: change spinnerRFPType.setSelection(dataAdapter1.getCount()-1); to spinnerRFPType.setSelection(dataAdapter1.getCount());

Comment: Hey it working as per expectation ..I wrote same code as above no change.check the screen shot .https://postimg.org/image/x15zi375j/
and this one
https://postimg.org/image/jyacytgxj/

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz I too think that it should work. But unfortunately it doesn't. Any idea how can it be corrected?

Comment: @h8pathak zip and send me your code .ITs impossible that it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Add this `android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"` to your spinner.

```
      <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />
```

Comment: This isn't the solution I was looking for. Also this needs a line                     `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement below method in your adapter class:

It will help you:

**Also for getCount return Count don't decrease it**

```
 @Override
 public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) 
 {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(null);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(theLayoutResID, parent,
            false);
    convertView= null;

    if(position == list.size() - 1)
    {
        holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        convertView= holder;
    }
    else{
         convertView= super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
    }
    return convertView;

}
```